# Form fields have null values after Edit except the ID

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, html, knockout.js, twitter-bootstrap-3

So,I have a table with an edit button in each row.When edit is clicked,the user is redirected to another page with the fields autopopulated.To achieve this,I am using Knockout binding.But when I Update the properties have only Null values in them,even though the fields are filled.I am using two way buinding,I dont understand what I am doing wrong.Any help would be appreciated folks.

HTML

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="col-sm-offset-2">Edit Provider Details:</h1>
    <br />
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="EditProviderDetailsForm" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label labelfont">FIRST NAME:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="Enter the First Name" id="FirstName" data-bind="value:FirstName" onkeypress="return onlyAlphabets(event);">
            </div>
            <label class="col-sm-4 labelfont errorMsg" id="Err_FirstName">Enter the first name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label labelfont">LAST NAME:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the Last Name" id="LastName" data-bind="value:LastName" onkeypress="return onlyAlphabets(event);">
            </div>
            <label class="col-sm-4 labelfont errorMsg" id="Err_LastName">Enter the last name</label>
        </div>
         <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label labelfont">CONTACT NUMBER:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value:ContactNumber" placeholder="Enter the Contact Number" id="ContactNumber" onkeypress="return onlyNumbers(event);" maxlength="13">
            </div>
            <label class="col-sm-4 labelfont errorMsg" id="Err_ContactNum">Enter the Contact Number</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label labelfont">EMAIL ADDRESS:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value:ContactEmail" placeholder="Enter your email address" id="EmailAddress">
            </div>
            <label class="col-sm-4 labelfont errorMsg" id="Err_EmailAddress">Enter the Email Address</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" id="Update" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-4">Update</button>
            <button type="button" id="Reset" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-1">Reset</button> 
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../App_Scripts/Edit_Jquery.js">   </script>
      <script type="text/javascript">var providerData = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))</script>
```

JS is as shown

```
 var ProviderEdit = function () {
var self = this;
self.ProviderID = ko.observable(providerData.ProviderID);
self.FirstName = ko.observable(providerData.FirstName);
self.LastName = ko.observable(providerData.LastName);
self.ContactNumber = ko.observable(providerData.ContactNumber);
self.ContactEmail = ko.observable(providerData.ContactEmail);
var Provider =
    {
        ProviderID: self.ProviderID,
        FirstName: self.FirstName,
        LastName: self.LastName,
        ContactNumber: self.ContactNumber,
        ContactEmail: self.ContactEmail,
    };
self.Provider = ko.observable();
}
 $(document).ready(function () {
   ko.applyBindings(new ProviderEdit());
   $("#EditProviderDetailsForm").validate({
    onfocusout: function (element, event) {
        this.element(element);
    },
    onkeyup: function (element, event) {
        if (event.which === 9 && this.elementValue(element) === '') {
            return;
        } else if (element.name in this.submitted) {
            this.element(element);
        }
    },
    rules:
        {
            FirstName: { required: true, minlength: 2, maxlength: 20 },
            LastName: { required: true, minlength: 2, maxlength: 20 },
            ContactNumber: { required: true, minlength: 10, maxlength: 10 },
            ContactEmail: { required: true, AcceptEmail: true }
        },
    messages: {
        FirstName: {
            required: "Please enter your first name",minlength: "Minimum 2 characters required",maxlength: "Maximum 20 characters allowed"
        },
        LastName: {
            required: "Please enter your last name",minlength: "Minimum 2 characters required",maxlength: "Maximum 20 characters allowed"
        },
        ContactNumber: {
            required: "Please enter your Contact Number",minlength: "Enter a 10 digit contact number",maxlength: "Enter a 10 digit contact number"
        },
        ContactEmail: {
            required: "Please enter your Email Address",AcceptEmail: "Please enter a valid email ID"
           }
       }
    });   
});
```

I am not posting the controller code since I am confident it will work if the data is fine.Kindly guide me in the right direction.

[image]

Comment: You say "But when I Update the properties have only Null values in them", do you mean in the update form or the view form? And "Update", you mean when you trigger the save action on the edit form?

Comment: When I Click on the update button,I am directed to the controller action,where all the fields are null except the ProviderID.Please check my edit.I have added an image to the same effect.Yes,I am triggering the save action on the Update form.

Comment: Are the values null on submission as well, or do they get sent properly but not received? Check the Update code to see if the variables are correct and filled before they're sent.

Comment: Since the Update button is a Submit button and in the form I have added the attribute method = 'post',I thought this would be enough to post the data.Am i wrong in my understanding?There is no specific code for Update.On the click of Update,I reach the controller.

Comment: And the form is pointing towards your webservice? Personally, I'd sniff the traffic to see if the variables are being delivered correctly, but I don't know if this is in the scope of what you can do. I've only used forms to POST to a PHP script, never to .NET webservice (which I presume you are using.)

Comment: Its not really a service.Its a just a default MVC application.I have my doubt on knockout.So,I am going to work on this issue from that angle.Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm sorry I couldn't provide a definite answer. I don't think knockout is your problem, since the values are on the form and it's being posted correctly. Maybe you could write a small php script and point the form at it to see if you get the values correctly? Good luck!